# Django: URL to specific request method

Tags: python, django, http-method

I'm working with Django and I'M using class-based views with urls. So, in mu classes I have the methods: `post`, `get`, `put` and `delete`.

Example:

```py
class MyClassView(View):
    def get(self, request, id=None):
        return HttpResponse('GET request')

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('POST request')

    def put(self, request, id):
        return HttpResponse('PUT request')

    def delete(self, request, id):
        return HttpResponse('DELETE request')
```

So in my URLs i have something like:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('my-class/', views.MyClassView.as_view()),
    path('my-class/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view()),
    path('my-class/create/', views.MyClassView.as_view()),
    path('my-class/update/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view()),
    path('my-class/delete/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view()),
]
```

This works fine! When I send a GET request to `/my-class` I get `"GET request"` and when a I send a POST request to `/my-class/create` I get `"POST request"` the same for others URLs.

The problem is, when I send a `POST` request to `/my-class/` I get `"POST request"` and when I send a `GET` request to `/my-class/creare` I get `"GET request"`

I need the URL to work only for a specific request method. That is, url `/my-class/create` should only work for the `POST` method, url `/my-class/update` should only work for the `PUT` method and so on.

How can I do this? I've researched a lot, in the documentation and even right here but found no solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `http_method_names` directly to the `.as_view()` method.
Tested on `Django==3.2.3`

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('my-class/', views.MyClassView.as_view(http_method_names=['get'])),
    path('my-class/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view(http_method_names=['get'])),
    path('my-class/create/', views.MyClassView.as_view(http_method_names=['post'])),
    path('my-class/update/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view(http_method_names=['put'])),
    path('my-class/delete/<int:id>/', views.MyClassView.as_view(http_method_names=['delete'])),
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried to develop a slightly lighter solution so you don't have to create a class for each request method.

Inspired by the operation of this feature in .NET Core I created a decotator to use in each method of the class. The code of this decorator is shown below:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def http_method_list(methods):
    def http_methods_decorator(func):
        def function_wrapper(self, request, **kwargs):
            methods = [method.upper() for method in methods]
            if not request.method.upper() in methods:
                return HttpResponse(status=405) # not allowed

            return func(self, request, **kwargs)
        return function_wrapper
    return http_methods_decorator
```

So in class we use:

```py
class MyView(View):

    @http_method_list(["GET"])
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Only GET requests")

    @http_method_list(["POST"])
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Only POST requests")

    # and so on
```

Now `get()` method, for example, can be only executed by a GET request, the same for `post()` and the other methods in a class View.

I hope this can be useful for someone else.

Comment: Seems like `HttpResponse(status=405)` is the same as [HttpResponseNotAllowed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed)

Comment: You're correct. Btw, if you are facing a similar issue I recommend you to look into the accepted answer. Django has a native solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the http methods using the `http_method_names`. But you should separate the view classes.

As an example:

```py
from .views import PostView

urlpatterns = [
    path('only_post/', PostView.as_view(), name='post'),
]
```

and your view:

```py
class PostView(View):
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('POST request')
```

Now you can only send a post request to this url, otherwise, you will get a *HTTP ERROR 405* error.

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, you can't use one view class for all of them (because there is no `get_http_method_names` method in the View class so that we can dynamically set this variable based on requested url).

Comment: Thanks @Pedram You is correct!

I was already aware of the solution, but I thought Django could offer me something more powerful.